# Управление асинхронным MediaPlayer из потока

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-mediaplayer

Имеется класс `BackgroundMusic`, унаследованный от `AsyncTask`, который занимается воспроизведением музыки в фоне:

```
public class BackgroundMusic extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{
private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    //инициализация mediaPlayer
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
    mediaPlayer.start();
    return null;
}

public void setVolume(int volume){
    mediaPlayer.setVolume(volume, volume);
}
```

В единственной активности создается экземпляр `BackgroundMusic`, в нем же дополнительный поток, откуда вызывается метод `setVolume` для статического экземпляра `BackgroundMusic` активности.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
public static BackgroundMusic backgroundMusic;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    backgroundMusic=new BackgroundMusic();
    gameThread=new GameThread(context);
    setContentView(new GameView(gameThread));
}
```

Но создается дополнительный поток, в котором начинает играть музыка и громкость `mediaPlayer` успешно регулируется, параллельно уже запущенному экземпляру `BackgroundMusic`(в нем громкость остается неизменной). В дебаггере отображается 3 `AsyncTask`, все в состоянии `WAIT` (хотя во всем коде создается 2 `AsyncTask`, один из которых BackgroundMusic). Приостановление всех `AsyncTask` ни к чему не приводит. Скорее всего, проблемы с синхронизацией, но я не могу правильно ее организовать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создайте `service`, в котором будет воспроизводиться музыка и происходить управление `MediaPlayer`ом.

В `onStartCommand()` распишите логику управления `MediaPlayer`ом, ну и `return START_STICKY` не забудьте.

Передавайте в сервис `Intent` с нужными параметрами, которые Вы будете разбирать в `onStartCommand()` и в зависимости от переданного управлять `MediaPlayer`ом.

P.S. А в Вашем случае `AsyncTask` запустил `MediaPlayer` и закончил свою работу.